# Loading animation with moving circles

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to improve my  CSS skills and I am trying to create [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4FnK.gif)  animation.

Here is my attempt. It works for **one** circle.
I don't know how to extend it for many.
For many, I immediately got stuck because you can see
my circles are having different speed (because apparently animation tries to fit them in given timeframe).

And also, after going to the left, then they become *one*
circle.

Help appreciated.

There is some minimal react code involved in my version.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="animation-container"
        style={{ padding: 100, border: '1px solid red' }}
      >
        {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              className="ball"
              style={{ left: i * 30, top: 100 }}
            ></div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.animation-container {
  position: relative;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  animation: default-ball 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes default-ball {
  25% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update: I futzed with the keyframes a bit to get it closer to what you're trying to achieve.

You can stagger the items in time via `animation-delay` and setting it to a negative value avoids the problem of the ball just sitting there waiting to go.

So get one ball to animate the full loop the way you want it, and then just add the others with a time offset.

```css
.animation-container {
  position: relative;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  animation: default-ball 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes default-ball {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;
  }
  5% {
    left: 100px;
    top: 60px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  95% {
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-container" style="padding: 100px;">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="animation-delay: -.4s"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="animation-delay: -.8s"></div>
  <div class="ball" style="animation-delay: -1.2s"></div>  
  <div class="ball" style="animation-delay: -1.6s"></div>  
</div>
```